# Trigger slideToggle when child li is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to work on a responsive navigation that once you click on one of the `li` links, the revealed menu (which had been revealed with a `slideToggle`) slides back up and out of the way of the content.

```
$( ".mini-nav" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
   $( ".nav" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
 });
```

Here's a link to a fiddle that demos what I have so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/bfLN2/1/

I'm not sure how to get it so it looks through the separate `li` anchors to then trigger it to slide back up.

Comment: The fiddle in link is empty :(

Comment: Well, haters gonna hate. I updated the link. I hope that works...geeze. Must be worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$( ".mini-nav" )
```

to:

```
$(".mini-nav, .nav li")
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bfLN2/2/)**

Answer (score -1):

However i suggest you to use the event on instead of click.

```
$( ".nav ul li, .mini-nav" ).on("click",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $( ".nav" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Check my demo http://jsfiddle.net/bfLN2/5/

Comment: Because you're not supposed to just post a JSFiddle. In fact you get a **warning in a big red box** NOT to do that without adding the code to your answer.